# Gnome Shell battery indicator shows 2 batteries

Tags: gnome, power-management, battery

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome edition with Gnome Shell 3.8.

The battery status indicator menu (the one that appears when clicking the battery icon on top bar) shows me two batteries whereas I only have one installed (Dell XPS 13).

The first battery seems to actually refer to my battery, the second is often shown as empty and the recharging symbol appears (lightning) even if nothing is actually recharging.
Why? How can I get rid of this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm I think I found out what it is: It seems that the second battery indicator shows the charge level of my bluetooth mouse battery... 
Can someone confirm that?

Comment: Try it by yourself: Let the battery get empty and laod it and watch the indicator.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing and then I got a notification saying my mouse battery is low. I was quite surprised that Gnome Shell knew that and that's when I realized that the second battery indicator was for my mouse.